# Facebook graph API upload photos to albums

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to upload photos to existing album with access_token

```
    $FILE_PATH='C:\\wamp\\www\\photo\\photo.jpg';
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $aid . '/photos?access_token='. $user_access_token, 'post', $args);

print_r($data);
```

I have a valid access_token with publish_stream permission. I have checked i have a valid access_token, but here is an error comming.

**> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An access token is required to request this resource. thrown in C:\wamp\www\photo\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 970**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the upload support to true. The following code works for me:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', array('image'=> '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH), 'message'=> 'Photo Caption'));
```

and furthermore, you will probably need the `user_photos`, `photo_upload`, and the `publish_stream` permissions.

Comment: @Asghar I've also tried it with an access token and got this error. Did you also try it without access token and let the fb api handle the correct user access token?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we need to set the access-token in the args,and then call to upload album, this was a fix that applied and it worked. thanks for your comments and answer,